# Syncronize SOA serial numbers explanation

Tags: debian, bind, dns-zone, soa-record

I made two successive mistakes while updating zone records. Once I forgot to increment the serial number, then next time I did put a digit more ie **20170210111** instead of **2017021011**, and each time I reloaded config : `rndc reload`.

When I realised it, I switched back serial to a 10 digits number, so my zone file SOA serial is now **2017021012**.

I get this now :

```
#  host -C domain.tld
Nameserver X.X.X.X:
        domain.tld has SOA record X.X.X.X.ovh.net. postmaster.domain.tld. 2017021010 28800 7200 1209600 3600
Nameserver Y.Y.Y.Y: 
        domain.tld has SOA record X.X.X.X.ovh.net. postmaster.domain.tld. 2017021003 28800 7200 1209600 86400
```

Where X.X.X.X is my primary DNS server IP and Y.Y.Y.Y secondary one.

I'm not really used to DNS configuration, and I really don't know **how to resynchronize serials and permit propagation**. I read already a lot of posts, I'm afraid I still don't know if I should give zone record a greater number, what happened when I reloaded with 13 digits...?

Comment: Restart your primary, verify it's showing the correct SOA.  Delete the domain's zone file on the secondary, restart the secondary.  It should pull from the primary again.

Comment: sorry for newbie question, which service do you suggest to restart ? And I can't delete the domain's zone on the secondary, since it is a provider IP. Tks

Comment: Why are you running your own DNS server in the first place?

Comment: @Sven Not sure of the vocab. I have a server with A.A.A.A Ip, on which a website with X.X.X.X IP(the one of the zone file above), and I declared A.A.A.A and a provider server Y.Y.Y.Y as NS records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `20170210111` is outside the range of a 32 bit integer, presumably the zone failed to load with the impossible to represent `SOA` record (check your logs).

First of all, verify (using eg `dig @master example.com SOA +norec`) that the master is now responding properly and with the current serial (`2017021012`). If not, `rndc reload` triggers a reload.

When the master works properly, the slaves should update on their next refresh (based on the `SOA` `REFRESH` interval). Also, assuming that the slaves are notify-aware and with proper configuration, you should be able to trigger an immediate refresh using [`rndc notify example.com`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.11/doc/arm/man.rndc.html), as well as automatically when loading a new version of the zone.

If this doesn't work I would think that your problem is something beyond having had an unloadable zone for a while.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so confused. @master beeing the primary DNS IP or the server IP ?

Comment: @Kojo The IP of the server with the master zone. (eg `@192.0.2.1`)

Comment: tks I did both and both return an old record despite a couple of reloads

Comment: @Kojo What do the logs say? What does `named-checkconf -zj` say?

Comment: a couple of syntax errors :( I may correct and try again

Comment: Ok I learned today :) . `named-checkconf -zj` did the trick. I didn't know how to test config before ! Now `dig @master example.com SOA +norec` returns updated serial. Thank you so much for your patience.